# Order a string by keywords

Tags: c#, string

I have some string and I would like to order the content.

```
string nr1 = "Number: 5 Specialty: Technology Role: Teacher";
string nr2 = "Specialty: Informatics Number: 1 Role: Student";
string nr3 = "Role: Teacher Specialty: Geography Number:10"
```

I would like to keep the following format: "Role: X Number: Y Speciality: Z";
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tryed already?

Comment: You could parse the string into a class with the 3 properties `Role`, `Number` and `Speciality`, then order the collection of objects with `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`

Comment: Do you have any control over the creation of those strings, or are you just given them like that?

Comment: What Phate01 said! The solution is to break your complex problem into two simple problems: (1) Parse the strings into appropriate data structures, (2) Output the data structure in the format you want. Separating data and its string representation is almost always a good idea and makes a lot of problems a lot easier! (I can't count the times I have read "How do I convert mm/dd/yy dates to dd/mm/yy dates" questions here on SO!)

Answer (score 4):

RegEx approach by parsing out the required values

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string nr1 = "Number: 5 Specialty: Technology Role: Teacher";
var n1 = Regex.Match(nr1, "(?<=Number: )\\w+");
var s1 = Regex.Match(nr1, "(?<=Specialty: )\\w+");
var r1 = Regex.Match(nr1, "(?<=Role: )\\w+");

string result = string.Format("Role: {0} Number: {1} Speciality: {2}", r1, n1, s1);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nu9MDg

Answer (score 3):

There are various approach to achieve it, I have done it by converting the string into list of strings. I hope this may help you out.

```
string nr1 = "Number: 5 Specialty: Technology Role: Teacher"; 

List<string> stringAsList = nr1.Split(' ').ToList();

StringBuilder reorderedString = new StringBuilder();

int indexRole = stringAsList.FindIndex(x => x.Contains("Role:"));
int indexNumber = stringAsList.FindIndex(x => x.Contains("Number:"));
int indexSpeciality = stringAsList.FindIndex(x => x.Contains("Specialty:"));

reorderedString.Append($"Role: {stringAsList[indexRole + 1]} Number: {stringAsList[indexNumber + 1]} Speciality: {stringAsList[indexSpeciality + 1]}");
```